# Should I use divide or subdivide in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to write something about an app for bus tracking.

> As a community-driven system, the application's users are *subdivided*
>   into three groups: inactive users (not riding the bus), bus riders,
>   and waiting for the bus.

Comment: Since this seems to be the "top-level" division, I would suggest simply "divided". If there's a second level in the hierarchy, you can start using "subdivided".

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to look into how to form plurals and punctuate. See our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **cat•e•go•rize** -
>
> 1. to arrange in categories or classes; classify.
> 2. to describe by labeling or giving a name to; characterize.

There are the eight groups by which words may be **categorized**, according to their roles in sentences:nouns adjectives ....

Answer (score 3):

Divided is the correct choice.  Subdivided is used where something has already been divided.  More particularly in the case of land parcels.

Comment: +1,Indeed, you divide and then sub-divide.